# generate jekyll posts from mp3 files

Tags: jekyll

**tl;dr** *Can I use mp3 files as posts in Jekyll? If yes, how?*

I have a list of mp3 files in the `_posts` folder, looking like

```
_posts/
  2014-02-23_john-doe_jekyll-and-hyde.mp3
  2014-02-25_jane-doe_ruby-is-king.mp3
  2014-03-02_joseph-doe_lalala-the-song.mp3
  {{date}}_{{author}}_{{title}}.mp3
  ...
```

and I would like jekyll to create a single post for every file, lets say like

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>by {{author}}, published on {{date}}</p>
<audio src="{{date}}_{{author}}_{{title}}.mp3" controls></audio>
```

as a pseudo template.

I've read about plugins for *generators* and *converters* in the [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/), and as I understand, I need to write a custom converter that converts my "markup language" (which is the filename of the mp3) to a html post. The main thing is

> Jekyll will only convert files that have a YAML header at the top, even for converters you add using a plugin.

what is obviously a problem with (binary) mp3 files - I can't add a YAML header here. Is there any way I can circumvent this?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if it's possible to get Jekyll to somehow "find" the MP3 files (without YAML header) and convert the filenames like in your example, so I'd suggest an alternative approach:

- Put the MP3s into a different folder (not in `_posts`).
- Write a small command-line utility in the language of your choice, that loops through all files in the MP3 folder, gets the data from the MP3 filenames and generates a Markdown file with the desired name and content in the `_posts` folder.
- Ignore the `_posts` folder in source control
- To build your site with a single command, write a shell script that first calls your command-line utility and then `jekyll build`

Of course, you can't use GitHub Pages if you do it this way *(except when you run the command-line utility on your machine and commit the `_posts` folder to source control)*.

**But IMO it's a question of using the right tool for the right job:

Maybe it *is* somehow possible to do all this in Jekyll, but that would be probably much, much more effort, compared to doing it in the language that you're most familiar with.**

Comment: I thought about the whole story as Jekyll is just as simple as I'd like it to be. But you are right, it is, in real, a "right tool right job" issue. This does not really answer the question (so, marking it as "accepted" would be misleading for people coming from google in my opinion), but I'll follow your approach and implement it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

MP3s would be considered 'Static Files' to Jekyll. You can't assign Front Matter to them directly, but can do so via defaults in your config files. The below documentation covers this.

See: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/

Something like the following would at least allow you to access some basic properties of these files in liquid...

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "assets/mp3"
    values:
      mp3: true
```

So then you could do this in liquid...

```
{% assign mp3_files = site.static_files | where: "mp3", true %}
{%- for mp3 in mp3_files -%}
  {{ mp3.path }}
{%- endfor -%}
```

**...That being said...**

I think a better approach would be to create a collection, assign your mp3 via front matter to each `.md` file in this new collection and then set `output: true` so Jekyll generates a page per item under the collection and the given mp3 file would be associated with that generated page. From that point on your new collection would have similar properties to a _post. A layout for these collection pages could do whatever with the mp3 files from that point using whatever libraries needed.

**See:** https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/